# Git push specific commit to remote branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have a Git repo hosted on Bitbucket. If I have 3 branches say `master`, `branch_2`, and `branch_3`. I have pulled down the `master` branch to my local machine which I've made a change on, committed and pushed. Now to keep things up to date I want to push that commit onto `branch_2` and `branch_3` how do I do that? I don't have those branches set up locally.

I've tried `git pull origin branch_2` to set up that branch locally but I'm now getting

> Auto-merging .gitignore CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in
>   .gitignore Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the
>   result.

Comment: Please read at least [this chapter from The Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) to get the idea of how local and remote branches interact, or, better, the whole [chapter on branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching) there.  Also please don't be obsessed by `git pull` -- too many developers for some reason are trying to use this command for everything. [This is wrong in many cases](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To checkout another branch, you have to do:

```
git checkout --track origin/branch_2
```

This creates a new local branch named `branch_2`, which is set up to be tracking the equivalent remote branch on `origin`.

Then `git pull` to fetch changes on that branch, in case you didn't pull already.

Next, you cannot push a commit, you can only push heads. What you want to do is to copy the commit between branches. And there's an easy command to do just that:

```
git cherry-pick master
```

This will copy the latest commit from the `master` branch into the current one. If you want a specific commit instead of the branch head, you can specify its SHA:

```
git cherry-pick 3f8917a
```

I would recommend using the `-x` parameter, which adds a comment indicating that this is a copied commit, and where it was copied from:

```
git cherry-pick -x master
```

After that, just `git push`.